# Cardinality of $\aleph_1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we are able to identify two disjoint, non-denumerable, infinite subsets,(A and B), of $\aleph_1$. Can anyone suggest a principle or procedure which would establish whether (or not) they share the same cardinality?

For example, what happens if we show that there is a bijective relation between each and every element of one such set, and an infinitely large subset of the other, (ie so that these secondary large subsets are disjoint)? Would this test suffice to prove that the cardinality of A and B is different?

Comment: Any uncountable subset of a set of size $\aleph_1$ has size $\aleph_1$; just fix an enumeration of the original set in type $\omega_1$, and consider the order type of your subset.

Answer (score 5):

If $A\subseteq\aleph_1$ and non-denumerable, then $\aleph_0<|A|\le\aleph_1$ and hence $|A|=\aleph_1$ since it is by defnition the smallest cardinal greater than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks, Tim